# jQuery: loading reCaptcha into a div via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, scripting, captcha, recaptcha

I want to create a form that has a div with id "captcha". When the user enters a wrong password, following code is generated in "login.php"

```
$myCaptcha=recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
$xml="<captcha><![CDATA[".$myCaptcha ."]]></captcha>";
echo $xml;
```

`recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);` generates this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=xxxx"></script> <noscript> <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=xxxx" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/> <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea> <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/> </noscript>
```

I want to get this code with $.post() and insert it into div "captcha". Doing something like this:

```
$.post("login.php", {requestCaptcha:"yes"}, function(returned){
     $("#captcha").html($("captcha",returned).text());
},"xml");
```

In IE, it does nothing. In Chrome, it clears up whole page and there is only the called reCaptcha script working like a charm.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks fine but with `$("captcha",returned).text()` what are you trying to do?  Is there a typo?

Comment: nope, what it should have been? when I type `$("#captcha").text($("captcha",returned).text());` , I can see it as text

Comment: anyways, I used reCAPTCHA AJAX API, and it works fine now.